# Matrix without a particular submatrix in R

Tags: r, matrix-indexing, submatrix

I have randomly generated a submatrix “train” from “mat” using the following:

```
train <- mat[sample(nrow(mat), size = 317, replace = FALSE),]
```

My question is, how do I then create “test” as a submatrix of “mat” which excludes the matrix “train”?

Thanks!

Comment: You start by assigning `inx <- sample(nrow(mat), size = 317, replace = FALSE)`. Then, `train <- mat[inx, ]` and `test <- mat[-inx, ]`. The negative index *excludes* those rows.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Just posted an answer and I realize it is the same as your comment. This is my first active day on SO, can you point me to when I should comment vs. give answers?

Comment: @JayCe Is your answer usefull to the OP and eventually to others? Then post it. The error is mine, I should have followed this rule and have not. Thanks for pointing this out, I will upvote your answer.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks for the clarification and the upvote - many tenured members also comment instead of answering that's why is was asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`train.index` are the indexes used for training.

```r
mat <- matrix(rnorm(20000),nrow=1000)
train.index <-sample(nrow(mat), size = 317, replace = FALSE)
train <- mat[train.index,]
test <- mat[-train.index,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzexRMFGVwFIFWVWaBTl5RflahgZGGjq5BXll9saGmhylRQlZubpZealpFYAVRYn5hbkpGqAZDWAmjR1FIozq1IVbBWMdRSKUgtyEpNBHDdHn2BXqFao8dFI5ujEcpWkFsMsjtZFkfoP5oEV/AcA)